# Установка rar через pecl

Tags: php, centos, pecl, rar

Не получается установить rar для php через pecl в
Centos 7 x 64 PHP 7.0.19

Вот полный текст процесса установки 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vox6od456a46x33/error.txt?dl=0

```
pecl -v install rar
downloading rar-3.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download rar-3.0.2.tgz (257,787 bytes)
....done: 197,328 bytes
md5sum ok: /usr/share/tests/pecl/rar/tests/001.phpt
md5sum ok: /usr/share/tests/pecl/rar/tests/002.phpt
md5sum ok: /usr/share/tests/pecl/rar/tests/003.phpt

тут ok, ok, ok ...

renamed source file /var/tmp/rar/.tmprar_navigation.c to /var/tmp/rar/rar_navigation.c
125 source files, building
building in /var/tmp/rar
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootPgR3Vp/rar-3.0.2
running: /var/tmp/rar/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed

.....

checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootPgR3Vp/rar-3.0.2/libtool --mode=compile cc -DRARDLL -DGUI -DSILENT -Wno-write-strings -Wno-logical-op-parentheses -I/var/tmp/rar/unrar -I. -I/var/tmp/rar -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootPgR3Vp/rar-3.0.2/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootPgR3Vp/rar-3.0.2/main -I/var/tmp/rar -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/rar/rar.c -o rar.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -DRARDLL -DGUI -DSILENT -Wno-write-strings -Wno-logical-op-parentheses -I/var/tmp/rar/unrar -I. -I/var/tmp/rar -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootPgR3Vp/rar-3.0.2/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootPgR3Vp/rar-3.0.2/main -I/var/tmp/rar -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/rar/rar.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/rar.o
In file included from /var/tmp/rar/rar.c:55:0:
/var/tmp/rar/php_rar.h:91:2: error: unknown type name 'zend_object_handle'
  zend_object_handle   id;
  ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c: In function '_rar_destroy_userdata':
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:164:3: warning: passing argument 1 of '_zval_ptr_dtor' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   zval_ptr_dtor(&udata->callable);
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /var/tmp/rar/rar.c:47:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_variables.h:112:15: note: expected 'struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
 ZEND_API void _zval_ptr_dtor(zval *zval_ptr ZEND_FILE_LINE_DC);
               ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c: In function 'zif_rar_wrapper_cache_stats':
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:406:31: error: macro "RETURN_STRINGL" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
  RETURN_STRINGL(result, len, 0);
                               ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:406:2: error: 'RETURN_STRINGL' undeclared (first use in this function)
  RETURN_STRINGL(result, len, 0);
  ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:406:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c: In function '_rar_unrar_volume_user_callback':
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:449:39: error: macro "ZVAL_STRING" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
  ZVAL_STRING(failed_vol, dst_buffer, 1);
                                       ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:449:2: error: 'ZVAL_STRING' undeclared (first use in this function)
  ZVAL_STRING(failed_vol, dst_buffer, 1);
  ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:451:5: error: 'zend_fcall_info' has no member named 'retval_ptr_ptr'
  fci->retval_ptr_ptr = &retval_ptr;
     ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:452:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  fci->params = &params;
              ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:456:7: error: 'zend_fcall_info' has no member named 'r 

..................... 


/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:645:2: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_find'
  zend_hash_find(cc->data, key, key_len, (void **) &element);
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /var/tmp/rar/rar.c:47:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:154:30: note: declared here
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *key);
                              ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c:649:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zval_add_ref' <br>from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   zval_add_ref(element);
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /var/tmp/rar/rar.c:47:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_variables.h:141:15: note: expected 'struct zval *' but argument is of type 'struct zval **'
 ZEND_API void zval_add_ref(zval *p);
               ^
/var/tmp/rar/rar.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-logical-op-parentheses" [enabled by default]
make: *** [rar.lo] Error 1
rolling back 391 file operations
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, на данный момент расширение для php - rar тестировалось при разработке с версией php 5.2. И соответственно максимальная версия php - 5.6 с которой можно поставить rar.